# cropping an image using canvas drawImage gives blurry image

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, google-chrome-extension

I am learning chrome extension development and trying to create a tool to capture crosshair screenshot. I use `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab` API to get the screenshot of whole visible area.

Now, I want to crop that visible area to what user selected using crosshair cursor. To crop that, I use HTML5 Canvas's `drawImage` method. **But for some reason, drawImage gives me blurry output**

[image]

This is my cropping function:

```
function cropImage(
  src: string,
  cropArea: { left: number; top: number; width: number; height: number }
): Promise<HTMLCanvasElement> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { left, top, width, height } = cropArea;

    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = src;
    img.onload = function () {
      // TODO: remove this: just for testing
      document.body.appendChild(img);

      try {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;

        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        const devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

        ctx.drawImage(
          img,
          left * devicePixelRatio,
          top * devicePixelRatio,
          width * devicePixelRatio,
          height * devicePixelRatio,
          0,
          0,
          width,
          height
        );

        resolve(canvas);
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    };
    img.onerror = function (event, source, lineno, colno, error) {
      reject(error);
    };
  });
}
```

This code is responsible for rendering the cropped Image:

```
      const canvas = await cropImage(response.imgSrc, {
        left: left - window.scrollX,
        top: top - window.scrollY,
        width,
        height,
      });

      const croppedImg = new Image();
      const croppedSrc = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
      croppedImg.src = croppedSrc;
      document.body.appendChild(croppedImg);
```

Checking other stackoverflow questions with similar issues, I tried some suggestions:

```
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

But it does not work.

I hereby agree that I have researched thoroughly before asking this question, so I don't think this is a duplicate of some other question. Please feel free to reach out incase if you think that this question is 100% duplicate of some other question.

**Note:** I think it will be helpful to mention that I am using Macbook Pro on which I get `window.devicePixelRatio = 2`.

---

**Update:**

As suggested by @kaidoo, I should not tell canvas to downsize the image, instead, I should tell img tag to downsize itself. That gives me the expected high quality result but its a hack. I am not supposed to only render the image on DOM. There can be anything done with the cropped image. So, I still feel that canvas should have handled it for me. Anyways, here is the code for this hackish way:

Here is the updated function:

```
export function cropImage(
  src: string,
  cropArea: { left: number; top: number; width: number; height: number }
): Promise<HTMLCanvasElement> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { left, top, width, height } = cropArea;

    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = src;
    img.onload = function () {
      // TODO: remove this: just for testing
      document.body.appendChild(img);

      try {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

        canvas.width = width * devicePixelRatio;
        canvas.height = height * devicePixelRatio;

        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.drawImage(
          img,
          left * devicePixelRatio,
          top * devicePixelRatio,
          width * devicePixelRatio,
          height * devicePixelRatio,
          0,
          0,
          width * devicePixelRatio,
          height * devicePixelRatio
        );

        resolve(canvas);
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    };
    img.onerror = function (event, source, lineno, colno, error) {
      reject(error);
    };
  });
}
```

And here is how I render it:

```
    const canvas = await cropImage(
      response.imgSrc,
      {
        left: left - window.scrollX,
        top: top - window.scrollY,
        width,
        height,
      }
    );

    const croppedImg = new Image();
    croppedImg.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
    document.body.appendChild(croppedImg);
```

And here is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: You do downsize the image by devicePixelRatio, which then will be upscaled in CSS. To keep the same quality you need to keep the same size between the crop and the output. However when brought back into DOM you'll need to tell the CSS to shrink it back.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for the reply. I can change my code to have the cropped Image that is not downsized and also, and I can have it handled by DOM as you said. Everything looks perfect! But I feel this hackish. Isn't there a clean way of doing things?

Comment: @Kaiido I have updated the question to reflect my comment. (please check update part in the question)

Comment: The canvas cannot create more pixels than it's been assigned. The CSS engine can and does on a high-density monitor. But even with bitmap images that don't come from a canvas, it can't generate high-resolution either. You need to pass explicitly high-res versions of the same image. It's the same in your case.

Comment: @Kaiido If possible, can you please post an example that demonstrates how to copy cropped image to clipboard at same visual size as it was cropped? Currently, when I do not downscale using canvas, if I copy the cropped image to clipboard, then when I paste it on slack, I get 2x version. If you want, I can provide my current code for copy to clipboard.

Comment: I saw some posts talking about having css size of canvas same and scaling the original size of canvas by multiplying with devicePixelRatio. But for some reason it does not work in my case. https://freedium.cfd/https://blog.devgenius.io/how-to-resize-a-canvas-on-high-resolution-screens-e96324a0617

Comment: .. There are 2 things at play here. The original size on your page is actually twice its display size. The browser knows your monitor is an high-res monitor and thus it knows it can use 4 dots per `px` and thus it can render 2x more information. This works only with objects that the browser renders from the beginning, e.g. text, element boxes etc. For a bitmap image that already contains its set of pixels it can't do that and thus it will render one pixel on 4 dots. A <canvas> is a bitmap image. So it holds only a limited set of pixels. This bitmap image doesn't know where it will be rendered.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for informative comment. I feel like, I have to learn more about such things before working more with canvas.